# cte,union,join in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
1   Pakistan    karachi 92
**2 Pakistan    Multan  92**
3   Pakistan    Sahiwal 92
4   Pakistan    Lahore  92
5   India       Mumbai  5541
6   India       Delhi   5541
7   India       Goa     5541
8   india       Amberser 5541
9   pakistan    Quetta  92
```

i have that result now i want following format from above table

```
id    column_name
1      pakistan
       karachi
       Multan
       Sahiwal
       Lahore
2      india
       Mumbai
       Delhi
       Goa
       Amberser
```

i want code with cte,union,join

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask]. Remember **SO is not a free code service!**

Comment: It is better to do this in the display layer rather than the DB unless you **really really** have to

Comment: This is more towards presentation layer work not much towards db

Comment: Anybody understand What i am saying ??????

Comment: @JohnHC Actually is very easy to do in the db as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Not saying it isn't easy, just better to do in the display layer as that is literally what the display layer is for.

Comment: @JohnHC well I just disagree, I rather have the data ready for display when possible. Why will I do a sort in the client side when can have the data already sorted from db?.

Comment: What about `Quetta`?

Comment: @ArsalanRazzaq have a look that script and implement in your requirement

Answer (score 2):

**Sample  Table script** :

```
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
        (Id int, name varchar(8), sname varchar(8), val int)
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1

    VALUES
    (1, 'Pakistan', 'karachi', 92),
    (1, 'Pakistan', 'karachi', 92),
        (2, 'Pakistan', 'Multan', 92),
        (3, 'Pakistan', 'Sahiwal', 92),
        (4, 'Pakistan', 'Lahore', 92),
        (5, 'India', 'Mumbai', 5541),
        (6, 'India', 'Delhi', 5541),
        (7, 'India', 'Goa', 5541),
        (8, 'india', 'Amberser', 5541),
        (9, 'pakistan', 'Quetta', 92)
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/VKC73902)**

**Script**:

```
   Select 
    CASE WHEN name  = Cname then ID ELSE NULL END ID,
    Cname from  (
    select DENSE_RANK()OVER( order by val )ID,
    name,
    Cname,
    val
             from @Table1
    CROSS APPLY 
    (values ('name',name), 
            ('sname',sname))CS(COL,Cname)
    GROUP BY name,Cname,val
    )T
    ORDER BY name DESC,CASE WHEN NAME = Cname then 0 ELSE 1 END 
;
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have modified the script as you asked .Please check

Comment: This is using your setup and returns the correct order, including `Quetta`: http://rextester.com/ATAOO67880 Nice practice, but still a quite silly requirement :-)

Comment: SO is all about providing solution whether it is silly  or irrelevant. we need to show him some confidence by giving a solution to his  problem ..hope it make sense @dnoeth ...cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try with **[DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql)**

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY your_numeric_column) as rank_id,
       country_name
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I include the link for dense_rank manual in the answer. That is an window function.

Comment: How is this going to return the expected result? Mixing country & city data?